# Karate - convert string to integer

Tags: karate

I have code like below. In the print statement, the correct value is being printed. I need to use that index for matching some values in json. In the match statement, I get an error like "Expected ?, ', 0-9, * ". It is taking 'index' as a string. How do I convert it into an integer?

I tried a few things like #(parseInt(index)) or #(1*index), but they did not work.

```
* def index = 0
* if (previousValue == 0) index = 1
* print 'index ', index
* match karate.jsonPath(response, "$.changelog.changes[index]...") == ["NEW"]
```